# Painting an image on a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton

I'm building a board game and I have a grid with empty circles.

- I created my own template (.png) of a single empty circle in photoshop and added it repeatedly (using a loop and layout manager) and used it to create multiple buttons and laid them out on a panel.

I created custom circular tokens (.png) in photoshop as well which will then sort of "fill up" or take the empty space in the circles upon the occurrence of an event. I hope you get what I mean.

I'm not entirely certain that using paint() is the only way to do this.

Could anyone drop a few hints on how I can achieve this? I'm new to GUI.

This is what my grid looks like:

[image]

[image]

And those empty white spaces are the spaces that the tokens I created will have to take up, but I'm not sure ho I will do that aside from familiarizing myself with paint()

This is the .png file that will "fill up" the empty spaces when the user clicks on a button

[image]

Comment: You know you don't have to paint them right? You can just use them as `Icon` for the button. `button.setIcon(icon)`. Or just `button = new JButton(icon);`

Comment: will `setIcon` just sort of add the token to the button, like "fill up" the empty space (I edited it so it fits in the empty space), and not remove the empty circle image i assigned to it before? because that's what i need, for both the token and square (the empty circle template) to be visible at the same time.

Comment: *"take the empty space in the circles upon the occurrence of an event."*  What event, specifically?  Can you show us the various icons?  Note that I suspect the best approach is to use a `JToggleButton` with the first icon as the default icon, and the combined icon as the 'pressed icon'.

Comment: "I have a grid with empty circles"
Can you give more details of this grid!

Comment: @AndrewThompson whenever a user clicks on a button i assigned to each column

Comment: OK, and what do the 'filled' parts look like?  If they're a solid color it is pretty easy.

Comment: @AndrewThompson `JToggleButton` seems like a good idea, but as far as my knowledge of GUI is concerned, it allows the user to toggle it off, and I can't allow that until the game is over (the user changing the token occupying a certain circle) or is there another way to work this around with `JToggleButton`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson unfortunately no, not just a solid color. It's a separate image file with a transparent background, I'll post a pic

Comment: @AndrewThompson it looks like this: http://imageshack.com/a/img854/5912/z8fk.png

Comment: Can you also load the template?  Those images seen in the question have a solid white BG, and I get the impression the template is actually *supposed* to have transparency.

Comment: *"or is there another way to work this around"*  Not easily.  It is also not easy coming up with the best approach while getting information in 'bits and pieces'..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay, here's the psd file then for the token template:
https://app.box.com/s/76o7kgsbrh2fclca7fmx
And for the grid: https://app.box.com/s/7u86cg1otdnjqj2gm114

It does have a transparent background. 
As for the grid, I just set the background of the panel to white, 
And yeah I know I'm probably asking for too much but I'm overwhelmed with Swing and not sure which I option should go for

Comment: If you'll preview them on the website they both do have transparent backgrounds

Answer (score 2):

Have a look over this for ideas. It combines the 2 images for the 'final logic' look:

[image]

I couldn't be bothered waiting for the transparent template, so I made my own. ;)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class GameGrid {

    public static BufferedImage getImage(BufferedImage image, boolean fill) {
        int pad = 4;
        BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(
                image.getWidth()+2*pad,
                image.getHeight()+2*pad,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = temp.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA.darker());
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(
                pad, pad, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        Rectangle2D.Double outline = new Rectangle2D.Double(
                0, 0, image.getWidth()+(2*pad), image.getHeight()+(2*pad));
        Area a = new Area(outline);
        a.subtract(new Area(ellipse));
        if (fill) {
            g.drawImage(image,pad,pad,null);
        }
        g.setClip(a);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth()+(2*pad), image.getHeight()+(2*pad));
        g.dispose();

        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5MFE.png");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);

        final BufferedImage img1 = getImage(image, true);
        final BufferedImage img2 = getImage(image, false);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));

                ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
                        b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
                    }
                };

                for (int ii=0; ii<9; ii++) {
                    JButton b = new JButton(new ImageIcon(img1));
                    b.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    //b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                    b.setBorder(null);
                    b.addActionListener(al);
                    gui.add(b);
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this. I have uploaded the transparent template though (it's in the comments; really sorry for the wait), if you don't mind, could you apply that? Only if you don't mind. :)

Comment: I'm so sorry here are the resized files:

TEMPLATE: http://imageshack.com/a/img191/8492/hloy.png
Token: http://imageshack.com/a/img842/6576/bz7j.png

Comment: Aah.. I was just about to say:  A) I don't understand how those two images are supposed to work together, being different sizes, and B) since I edited my answer with better padding and a BG color, I really couldn't be bothered making further alterations without seeing a 'best attempt' on *your* part.  Have a close look over the code and see if you can edit it to combine the template and fill image.  Post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example) of your best attempt, if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes of course. Thank you so much for the time and effort, I'm already getting the hang of your code, though I think I'm gonna have a little problem with not simply using a plain color as the outline, but actually using the .png template, but I'm gonna go try and see what I'll end up with and then I'll return here. Thank you!

Comment: OK.. here's a tip.  Change the `getImage` method parameters to accept two images.  Paint the 'circle' image first, then the 'template' image.  Most of the rest of it can be deleted (dealing with `Area` objects).